# Using iterated integrals to get the area with strict conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area, iterated-integrals

We were tasked to use iterated integrals over this area shaded in yellow here:
[image: Area to find]

I'm confused as to how to approach this as I've only seen ones that encompass the whole space inside the closed shape made by functions. How would you suggest I go about this problem? do we break it to pieces or something? Should I just horizontally cut it up and set the upper bound to 4 and lower bound to 0? What would be a good approach for this?

Comment: I don't really see a need for iterated integrals here. Find the point of intersection, which happens at $x=1$, then simply do $\int_1^2 (f(x)-g(x))dx + \int_2^4 f(x)dx$.

Comment: @Prometheus I kind of get the ∫21(f(x)−g(x))dx part but I'm confused with the ∫24f(x)dx? If I were to get the area for that part then would I not include everything below the positive y-axis from which I am trying to avoid?

Comment: Integral is defined as area between the graph and the x-axis. Since the red line crosses the x axis at x=2, it's no longer f(x)-g(x) since now the baseline is no longer the red line, but the x-axis

Comment: Oh right. That makes sense now. Thanks a lot, @Prometheus.

Comment: $f(x) = f(x) - 0$, which means you are accumulating the area between (height) $f$ and (height zero) the $x$-axis.